# Android ARM v7 emulator

Tags: android, arm

Can anyone please guide me on how to start a Android  ARM v7 emulator from eclipse. I understand that Android eclipse based emulator is Arm V5. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! AVD Arm7 Not supported yet!
You will need to use real device for development.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/a19fc6df3d661d79?pli=1

If there is pre-compiled arm7 AVD image for intel, please leave message here!